# How do we find that the complement of the set of integers is an open interval as shown below?

Tags: general-topology

I want to know what method is used to arrive at this answer:
$\mathbb{R}∖\mathbb{Z}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1)$.

Comment: As per the guidelines to ask questions, you should show what you have tried yourself.

I'm a little confused by your question. Do you want to know how the author came to this conslusion intuitively, or do you want to know how to prove the equality?

If you want to prove the equality, do you know how to prove set equalities in general?

Comment: I want to know how the author came to the conclusion

Comment: Well, I would imagine he did it visually. Imagine the real line, and then remove all the integers. What is left between, say, 3 and 4? 4 and 5? You should be able to see that all intervals between to consecutive integers is in this set, and after that you write it down formally like the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the integers (so all $n \in \Bbb Z$) what we're left with are all the non-integers, so precisely all points that are *inbetween* the integers, which we can write as $$\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb Z} (n, n+1)$$ Every real number $x$ has a unique integer part $\lfloor x \rfloor = \max \{z \in \Bbb Z\mid z \le x\}$ and then if $x \notin \Bbb Z$, $x \in (\lfloor x \rfloor, \lfloor x \rfloor+1)$, and so is in that union of open intervals.

It's quite obvious if you know just a bit (like high school level) about real numbers, and is nothing "deep".

Comment: I now get the hang of it